# Unity build Errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build

So ive made my game and tried to'build it. I get a couple of errors that mean nothing to me.

Here's the errors:

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00234] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:191 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:97 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

UnityException: Build path contains project built with "Create Visual Studio Solution" option, which is incompatible with current build settings. Consider building your project into an empty directory.
UnityEditor.WindowsStandalone.WindowsDesktopStandalonePostProcessor.CheckSafeProjectOverwrite (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WinPlayer/Extensions/Managed/WindowsDesktopStandalonePostProcessor.cs:58)
DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.cs:43)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

It should build and run right. It currently does not do so. Any help will be appreciated. :D

Comment: Did you read the message and pick an empty directory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> UnityException: Build path contains project built with "Create Visual Studio Solution" option, which is incompatible with current build settings. Consider building your project into an empty directory.

sounds pretty self-explanatory.

Before you have built the project with that option enabled, now you are trying it without.

[image]

Either

- A. Enable that option again if you want to create a VS solution
- B. Delete the content created by the former build or
- C. As the exception suggests simply choose another target folder for the new build.