# Why is GUI.Label not working for me in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried both without OnGUI and with OnGUI and I can not really understand the errors they are giving.
I do not really understand what an error like

```
Internal build system error. BuildProgram exited with code -2146233088.
error:  Build path contains project built with "Create Visual Studio Solution" option, which is incompatible with current build settings. Consider building your project into an empty directory.
System.Exception: Build path contains project built with "Create Visual Studio Solution" option, which is incompatible with current build settings. Consider building your project into an empty directory.
   at WinPlayerBuildProgram.WinPlayerPrerequisiteChecks.CheckSafeProjectOverwrite(PlayerBuildConfig playerBuildConfig)
   at WinPlayerBuildProgram.WinPlayerBuildProgram..ctor(String[] args)
   at PlayerBuildProgramTypeWrapper.Run(String[] args)
   at Program.Main(String[] args)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun ()
```

means and I do not know the problem with this code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class SquareScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(1, 0);
    }

    void Update()
    { 
        transform.position = new Vector3((float)Math.Cos(Time.time), (float)Math.Sin(Time.time));
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), "lol");
    }
}
```

And by the way it has nothing to do with the stuff in `void Start()` or `void Update()` since I tested that without the GUI stuff and it works fine.

Comment: What U3d version are you using?

Comment: I was trying to tag unity2d but that does not work. It has nothing to do with it being 3d or 2d I think, but the unity version I am using is 2021.3.16f1

Comment: Sorry I found a way to solve this problem in another question. Sorry for wasting time. Just in case someone encounters this again here is the link to the answer; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844138/unity-build-errors

Comment: Sounds like you have made a build before with a different target platform .. are you building into an empty folder like the error suggests? Doesn't seem related to the `OnGUI` though